# RegisterEventSource and multiple EventMessageFile valuenames under the same event log => the first one match? depth-first or width-first match?

Tags: c++, event-log

This is a continuation of [RegisterEventSource(0, "App1.exe") => what if there are multiple "App1.exe"s under ...\Eventlog registry key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69994034/).

I have another question about the `"EventMessageFile"` value names in the Registry. For example, Chrome has an `EventMessageFile` value right under the `Chrome` subkey, while `Windows PowerShell` has it under one lower level, that is under the `Windows PowerShell\PowerShell` subkey.

Will `RegisterEventSource()` search through all the deepest levels until it finds the first `EventMessageFile` value? What if there exists multiple `EventMessageFile` values under the same log? Will it search depth first or width first? Neither MSDN nor internet tells anything about this.

Answer (score 1):

The details about `EventMessageFile` are documented on MSDN:

[Event Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/event-sources)

> Each event source contains information (such as a message file) specific to the software that will be logging the events, as shown in the following table.
>
> | Registry Value | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | EventMessageFile | Path to one or more event message files; use a semicolon to delimit multiple files. An event message file contains language-dependent strings that describe the events. This value can be of type REG_SZ or REG_EXPAND_SZ. |

Both examples you present are storing the `EventMessageFile` value in an event source key:

- `Application\Chrome` is an event source named `Chrome` of the `Application` log.
- `Windows PowerShell\PowerShell` is an event source named `PowerShell` of the `Windows PowerShell` log.

So, to answer your question: "*Will it search depth first or width first?*" - the answer is **Neither**. There can only be 1 `EventMessageFile` per event source, but there can be multiple event sources per log. `ReportEvent()` will simply use the `EventMessageFile` of whichever event source `RegisterEventSource()` successfully opens a handle to. It doesn't have to search the Registry for the value at all, it already knows the exact key to look for it in.

Comment: Hi @Remy Lebeau, could you help me with the following ticket?  No one answers yet and need your help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70000713/event-log-file-not-created-how-to-fix